# Delphi debug output folder attributes

Tags: delphi, windows-7, attributes, delphi-xe8

I am trying to figure out how I can set the default attributes on the folders that delphi created when it builds a project. All my googling has provided no answer.

For example:

Say I have a delphi project at `C:\MyProject\myProject.dpr`. When I build this project, Delphi will create `C:\MyProject\Win32\Debug\` folders. 
The `Win32\Debug\` folders comes from `Tools - Options - Environment Options - Delphi Options - Debug DCU Path`.

The Problem is the `Debug` folder delphi created has the Read-Only attribute checked.  With that folder being Read-Only, I get frequent build errors, like:

```
[fatal error] could not create output file C:\MyProject\myProject.exe
```

If I manually uncheck the Read-Only attribute I can build my project fine.

So does anyone on SO know how to tell Delphi to create this folder without being Read-Only?

(I am using Delphi XE8 but I believe this applies to all versions and Windows 7 Professional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders are created with a call to `CreateDirectory` that passes `NULL` as the `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter. As documented this means that:

> If lpSecurityAttributes is NULL, the directory gets a default security descriptor. The ACLs in the default security descriptor for a directory are inherited from its parent directory.

In other words the security settings are inherited from the parent. You can make this directory writeable by making its parent writeable.

Comment: For the OP's sake, I suppose one ought to hope that his project directory isn't really in the root of C:.

Comment: Why, @Martyn? He doesn't need to make the root folder writable for this, just the project directory.

Comment: @RobKennedy I know, but I was just meaning if he took David's "making its parent writeable" literaly

Comment: @David Thank you, this has been bothering me for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over how the folders are created.  There is no option to specify the desired attributes.  However, you can try using a [Pre-Build event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Build_Events) to execute a command-line script that manually changes the folder attributes before compiling begins.